# d3 - multiple overlaying charts with custom DOM element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to d3, but pretty familiar with the HighCharts api.

I've seen lots of examples of multiple d3 charts on the same page; but can't seem to find examples of one chart overlaying/sitting directly on top of another chart. Is this possible?

With HighCharts, you can define multiple chart types in the `plotOptions` config object. Is there something similar with d3? Or, how could you do this with d3?

I would effectively like to have a line graph on top of a bar chart. There will be different 'stages' according to the data, so some of the bar's could be inactive/empty.

Additionally, I need to display an indicator to show where the 'stage' is currently; and ensure that this is all responsive.

Example (rough mockup):

[image: desired chart/s mockup]

After researching d3 and looking for similar examples, I am thinking that maybe d3 isn't the best choice for this; maybe a custom CSS/JS/HTML solution (inside an angular app) would be better.

Any recommendations or pointers would be very appreciated.

Comment: You can definitely do this. Arguably, d3 is exactly the way to achieve what you refer to as a "custom CSS/JS/HTML" solution. Unlike HighCharts, d3 is not a framework where you pass configuration into a predefined chart object. With d3 you get to build the chart from scratch. It's much like you'd do it with, say, jQuery, except d3 is more geared towards rendering data-driven graphics. So if you can figure out how to render a trendline with d3 and how to render a barchart with d3 then you can layer the two by rendering each one into its own `<g>` container within a single SVG.

Comment: c3.js is a d3 based charting library that can do overlaying for some charts. See http://c3js.org/samples/chart_combination.html for an example.

Comment: Thank you all. Will spend some time on this; we might be simplifying this as well for a version 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick mock-up started from this [excellent bar chart](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304) example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.point rect {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.point circle {
  fill: orange;
}

.point rect:hover {
  fill: brown;
}

.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: orange
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 75, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


  var data = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("").map(function(d){
    return {
      letter: d,
      bar: Math.random() * 10,
      line: Math.random() * 10
    };
  })
  
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max([d.bar, d.line]); })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text");

  var points = svg.selectAll(".point")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "point");
    
    points.append('rect')
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.bar); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.bar); });
      
    points.append('circle')
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("cx", function(d){ return x(d.letter) + x.rangeBand() / 2; })
      .attr("cy", function(d){ return y(d.line)});
      
  var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.letter) + x.rangeBand() / 2; })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.line); });

  svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("d", line);
    
  var indicator = svg.append("g")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (x("q") + x.rangeBand() / 2) + "," + -20 + ")");
    
  indicator.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 40)
    .style("fill", "red");
    
  indicator.append("text")
    .text("!")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("alignment-baseline", "middle")
    .style("font-size", 70);
  
  indicator.append("line")
    .attr("y1", 20)
    .attr("y2", height + 20)
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("x2", 0)
    .style("stroke", "red")
    .style("stroke-width", "4px");

</script>
```

---

**New Solution Based on Comments**

Given your input data, here's a new example.  I went a bit overboard here, so please ask question on any confusing bits.  I tried to comment it out:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  rect {
    fill: steelblue;
  }
  
circle {
    fill: orange;
  }
  
  rect:hover {
    fill: brown;
  }
  
  .axis {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
  }
  
  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
  
  .x.axis path {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: orange
  }
</style>

<body>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var margin = {
        top: 75,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 40
      },
      width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left");

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // here's your data
    var data = 
    {
      'point1': [{
        'value': 50
      }, {
        'value': 100
      }, {
        'value': 100
      }, {
        'value': 150
      }],
      'point2': [{
        'value': 25
      }, {
        'value': 40
      }, {
        'value': 60
      }],
      'point3': [{
        'value': 25
      }]
    };
    
    // d3ify your data
    // d3 likes arrays of objects, you have an object of objects
    // so first make it an array
    var barData = d3.entries(data);
    // set x domain
    x.domain(barData.map(function(d){ return d.key }));
    // create lineData
    var lineData = [];
    barData.forEach(function(d0, i){
      d0.mean = d3.mean(d0.value, function(d1){ return d1.value });
      d0.max = d3.max(d0.value, function(d1){ return d1.value});
      var N = d0.value.length,
        // this is an inner scale
        // that represents each bar
        s = d3.scale.linear().range([
          x(d0.key) + (x.rangeBand() / N) / 2,
          x(d0.key) + x.rangeBand()
        ]).domain([
          0, N
        ])
      d0.value.forEach(function(d1, j){
        lineData.push({
          x: s(j), // this is the pixel position of x, it's jittered on the bar
          y: d1.value // this is the user position of y
        })
      });
    });

    // set y domain
    y.domain([0, d3.max(barData, function(d) {
      return d.max;
    })]);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text");

    // draw bars
    var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(barData)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'bar')
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.key);
      })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.mean);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y(d.mean);
      });
    
    // add points
    var points = svg.selectAll('point')
      .data(lineData)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'point')
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x; // already pixel position
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y(d.y)
      });

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return d.x; // already pixel position
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.y);
      });

    svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .datum(lineData)
      .attr("d", line);

    var indicator = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (x("point2") + x.rangeBand() / 2) + "," + -20 + ")");

    indicator.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 40)
      .style("fill", "red");

    indicator.append("text")
      .text("!")
      .style("fill", "white")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("alignment-baseline", "middle")
      .style("font-size", 70);

    indicator.append("line")
      .attr("y1", 20)
      .attr("y2", height + 20)
      .attr("x1", 0)
      .attr("x2", 0)
      .style("stroke", "red")
      .style("stroke-width", "4px");
  </script>
```

Happy d3ing!

Comment: Absolutely fantastic, thank you Mark! I wasn't expecting a complete example - this is great! I've learnt a lot from this already. I'm adapting this solution and allowed for responsive support. I'll post another answer with this for anyone else.

Comment: With this approach, how can you have multiple circle elements for each 'point'? Obviously coming from the data, some 'points' could have 3 circles, others could have 7 for example. I think I can work out the coordinations aspect of it, but how to append multiple circles depending on the data?

Comment: I'll probably end up having data looking something like this. Any help or guidance would be v.appreciated - really scratching my head with this one. `{
            'point1': [ {'value':50},{'value':100},{'value':100} ],
            'point2': [ {'value':25},{'value':40} ],
            'point3': [ {'value':25} ],
            'point4': [ {...}, {...}  ]
        }`

Comment: @TonyBarnes, it all depends on the x-scale.  In this case I've used an ordinal scale, this maps a pixel position to a discrete value (in this case a, b, c, d, etc...)  In your case though, it sounds like you have a numeric x-scale.  In that case you should use a [linear scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear) (which maps it to a number).  Give me a few minutes and I'll update my code sample above.

Comment: @TonyBarnes, I take it back, looks like you still have discrete values (point1, point2, etc..), so how would you display the points?  All at the same x value?  with a little [jitter](http://thomasleeper.com/Rcourse/Tutorials/jitter.html)?

Comment: brilliant, that's smart! The inner scale and jittering seems v.sensible. Previously I was trying to loop over elements and append with cords, without the inner scale. Data is flexible - I can strip what I need and create a new array, maybe with a grouping kind of thing, for d3 needs.

Comment: Thank you very kindly - d3 is a universe! I'm learning a lot from this already :-)